# how to read multibyte chars without knowing their code page on mac using c++

Tags: c++, macos, unicode, iconv

I'm trying to read some multibyte chars on mac, but the the their code page is unknown. Is there a way to read them and convert them to utf-8? the locale and region can be used, is there a way to connect them to the corresponding code page info?
for example, I want to translate '\xbf\xa7' which represent chinese charactor "咖".

Now I'm using iconv to convert the charactors, but it requires the code info:
my code is as below:

```
char src=[] ="\xbf\xa7";
char dst[100];
size_t srclen=3;
size_t dstlen=6;
char *pIn=src;
char *pOut =(char*)dst;

iconv_t conv= iconv_open("UTF-8","GBK");
iconv(conv,&pIn,&srclen, &pOut,&dstlen);
iconv_close(conv);
fprintf(stderr,"out: %s\n",dst);
```

Thank you!

Update:
Is there a way to determine the encoding of the system? so I can use it as from code for iconv_open?

Comment: in multibyte charactesr, how is any software supposed to know what character you mean by a certain combination of bytes unless you specify the codepage? There is no way around specifying a codepage. There might be some heuristic to determine the codepage (e.g. depending on the frequency with which certain values appear), but that can never be 100% accurate

Comment: It's impossible to do for certain in general.

Comment: I agree. Sorry for not being specific, on windows, the function MultiByteToWideChar can take CP_ACP as its code page and use the correct one. Is there a similar method on mac? Thank you!

Comment: I believe the default encoding on OS X is UTF-8 regardless of locale.